# Two different actions being performed

Tags: html, node.js, angular

I have in this code a method openItem(anuncio, operacao)" that runs when I click on the object that will perform the action. In this case I don't understand why when running (click) = 'checkFavorite (advert) he also performs the action. Clicking the verifyFavorite action should only run it and not openItem. Could anyone help me? thanks !!!

```
    <div class="ali-container">
        <div class="ali-linha">
            <div class="ali-capa-livro">
                <button *ngIf="operacao !== vis" class="ali-capa-livro-btn" (click)="openItem(anuncio, operacao)">
                    <img src="{{anuncio.publicacao.imagem}}" width="40%" height="40%" />
                </button>
                <button *ngIf="operacao === vis" class="ali-capa-livro-btn">
                    <img src="{{anuncio.publicacao.imagem}}" width="40%" height="40%" />
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="ali-detalhes-livro">
                <div class="ali-titulo-livro">{{anuncio.publicacao.titulo}}</div>
                <div class="ali-autores-livro linha-unica-elipissis">{{anuncio.publicacao.autores}}</div>
                <span class="ali-preco">{{anuncio.preco | currency:'R$':'code'}}</span>
                <span class="ali-conservacao">({{anuncio.tipoConservacao}})</span>
                <div class="ali-anunciante linha-unica-elipissis">por {{anuncio.usuario.nome}}</div>
                <div class="ali-anunciante linha-unica-elipissis">{{anuncio.statusAnuncio}}</div>
                <span>Anúncio: {{anuncio.tipoAnuncio.nome}} {{anuncio.tipoAnuncio.valor | currency:'R$':'code' }}</span>
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="operacao !== vis">
                <button mode="ios" class="botao-excluir-anuncio" (click)="excluir(tipo, anuncio._id, favorito)" ion-button
                    round text-center item-end>
                    <ion-icon name="trash" item-end></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div *ngIf="operacao === vis">
        <div *ngIf="!anuncio.favorito">
            <button mode="ios" class="botao-naoefavorito-anuncio" (click)='verificarFavorito(anuncio)' ion-button round
                text-center item-end>
                <ion-icon name="ios-heart-outline" item-end></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="anuncio.favorito">
            <button mode="ios" class="botao-favorito-anuncio" (click)='verificarFavorito(anuncio)' ion-button round
                text-center item-end>
                <ion-icon name="ios-heart" item-end></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="apenasexcluir === 1">
            <button mode="ios" class="botao-excluir-anuncio" (click)="excluir(tipo, anuncio._id, favorito)" ion-button round
                text-center item-end>
                <ion-icon name="trash" item-end></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>



import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Anuncio } from '../../models/anuncio';
import { AppBasePage } from '../../pages/app-base-page/app-base-page';
import { AnuncioDetalhePage } from '../../pages/anuncio-detalhe/anuncio-detalhe';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AppGlobal } from '../../app/app.global';
import { AppRestService } from '../../services/app-rest.service';
import { RestNovoFavorito } from '../../services/app-rest.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'anuncio-list-item',
    templateUrl: 'anuncio-list-item.html'
})
export class AnuncioListItemComponent extends AppBasePage {

    @Input('anuncio') anuncio: Anuncio;
    @Input('tipo') tipo: any;
    @Input('favorito') favorito: any;
    @Input('cesta') cesta: any;
    @Input('operacao') operacao: any;
    @Input('apenasexcluir') apenasexcluir: any;
    @Output() onExcluir: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() onDetail: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private rest: AppRestService, private appGlobal: AppGlobal, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

        super();

    }

    openItem(anuncio, operacao, apenasexcluir) {
        // quando origem cesta, chama com o parametro para atualizar a cesta de acordo com o anuncio alterado
        if (this.cesta) this.navCtrl.push(AnuncioDetalhePage, { anuncio: anuncio, operacao: operacao, apenasexcluir: apenasexcluir, cesta: this.cesta });
        else this.navCtrl.push(AnuncioDetalhePage, { anuncio: anuncio, operacao: operacao, apenasexcluir: apenasexcluir});
    }

    excluir(tipo, id, favorito) {
        if (tipo == 1) {
            this.onExcluir.emit(favorito);
        } else
            this.onExcluir.emit(id);

    }

    verificarFavorito(id) {
        if (id.favorito) {
            this.excluirFavorito(id.favorito._id)
        } else {
            this.incluirFavorito(id._id)
        }
    }

    async excluirFavorito(id) {
        await this.rest.excluirAnuncioFavorito(id);
    }

    async incluirFavorito(id) {
        let restNovoFavorito = new RestNovoFavorito();
        restNovoFavorito.anuncio = id;
        await this.rest.incluirFavorito(restNovoFavorito);

    }


}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, please provide a stackblitz reproducing the issue.

Comment: Can you show the .ts file for this component?

Comment: hello I added the ts file

Comment: As I already mentioned, your code works fine **based on what we are seeing**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lzmhlu?file=pages/home/home.html Please provide a [mcve]